# Is it possible to translate (Revit) models from non-Autodesk cloud storage services using Forge Model Derivative API?

Tags: autodesk, revit, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I just tried some of the [Forge boilerplates on Github](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs).

Some examples asked me to login to BIM 360 to fetch some model data. I was wondering if it would be possible to load the (Revit) models from Dropbox, Google Drive or OneDrive, or even upload them from the local storage?

PS: Forge is awesome, kudos to Forge Team!

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma please write it as an answer so I can accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have multiple examples that illustrate how to integrate Forge with cloud storage providers under the same github org:[model.derivative-nodejs-box.viewer](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/model.derivative-nodejs-box.viewer), [data.management-nodejs-integration.box](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-nodejs-integration.box), [model.derivative-nodejs-google.drive.viewer](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/model.derivative-nodejs-google.drive.viewer)

The point of using 3-legged API is precisely to let your app access customer data that is already hosted on Autodesk Cloud. If you want use a storage mechanism that is specific to your app, then you need to use 2-legged Object Storage Service, see [Create an App-Managed Bucket and Upload a File](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/app-managed-bucket/)

In order to fire a translation on a CAD file, you have to upload your data to Autodesk Cloud first, you can then load it from there in the viewer. However you could also download the svf package using the API and then serve those as static resources from your own server. Take a look at this sample for more info: [extract.autodesk.io](https://extract.autodesk.io/).

Hope that helps

Comment: perfect, you answered all my questions :)

Comment: just a side note, please consider Revit I/O so we can write back to the Revit file. [flux.io](https://twitter.com/flux_io/status/803622166998749184) and some others are doing this with workarounds but it would be better if we could use the Forge api.

Comment: Thanks, This is definitely coming, unfortunately I can't give you any official timeline about public availability.